# Why doesn't the output get redirected into the file?

Tags: io-redirection

have the following command line that outputs vmstat every second with a time stamp on each line via the perl script:

```
vmstat 15 | /home/Beer/addtimestamp.pl > File_1
```

the contents of the addtimestamp.pl:

```
!/usr/bin/perl while (<>) { print localtime() . ": $_"; }
```

So why doesn't the output get redirected to the "File_1" file?

It works perfectly when I don't, it prints out the output perfectly every second with no issues at all.

Comment: There's a utility to do this: [ts](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ts), part of the [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fell into the buffering Gotcha. Perl buffers its output and only writes out to disk when the buffer is full. Buffering is a good thing performance-wise, but at low data rates can be confusing. If you wait long enough you'll notice your file being written (check with `tail -F File_1`). I believe standard buffer is 4kB in size.

Add `$|=1` like below to disable buffering in Perl:

```
vmstat 1 | perl -e '$| = 1; while (<>) { print localtime() . ": $_"; }' > /tmp/fileetje
```

Comment: I just add '$|=1' to the start of the script and it worked like a Charm!

Wait, that's actually correct, why am I using two scripts when I can just merge both!, Awesome Dude!

Thanks!